# Changing MemberAccessExpression with Rolsyn analyzer

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a blank Net Core Web project and I want to modify CreateHostBuilder method.

I just want to add custom configuration to existing code:

```
IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

It must look like:

```
IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                  .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) => { 
                        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.custom.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true); })
                  .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                    {
                        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    });
```

I tried to use CSharpSyntaxRewriter instances to find VisitMemberAccessExpression (CreateDefaultBuilder) and add my code, but my code was inserted between CreateDefaultBuilder and (args) parameters list.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. why you can not simply add your configuration to your empty project !?

Comment: I just need to create VS extension which will make some code changes in existing solution.

Comment: hmm ... now it makes sense